# How does the kinetic energy of a falling object affect the wave amplitude?

Tags: energy, waves, water

Which formulas would be useful for this problem? assuming that all the energy is transferred from the falling object to the water waves. The kinetic energy of the object would be transferred to gpe of the water and all the energy would be moved up in the wave, so then I would know how much energy is going into the waves.

Then the more complicated part comes, which I don't exactly understand. How would I go on to find the amplitude from that point forward. A friend of mine suggested modelling with sine function, so I would be able to find the mass of the waves with various amplitudes, but I'm not sure about that.

Furthermore, I found equation such as $E=\frac{1}{8}\rho gh^2$ and $E\propto A^2$.

If someone could give me a push in the right direction as this will be important for my diploma.
Thank you!

Comment: I somehow don't believe in this. Most likely that due to collision most kinetic energy will be transferred to _initial_ shockwave, which just dissipate as splashes and "temporary water wall". Then you will get extinct waves, from the rest of remaining energy, but it should not depend much on initial kinetic energy. For getting normal waves, you need collision with water to be _periodic_ and that depends on many parameters like collision frequency, volume of displaced water per second and etc.

Comment: It is discussed on  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30288/waves-on-water-generated-by-a-falling-object